# Facebook app token not working, but access token works

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a really weird situation here, and I've looked everywhere through Facebook's documentation with no answers.

I'm trying to get get recent posts from multiple Facebook pages. But one of them keeps crashing. It won't work when I'm using an app token. It works if I'm using access tokens, but those expire, so it'd be better to not use that.

https://graph.facebook.com/norgeshushonefoss/posts?access_token=myAppToken

gives this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

While this url gives me the recent posts: https://graph.facebook.com/norgeshus/posts?access_token=myAppToken

I can't see any difference in those two. Are there any page settings that may cause an app token not to authorize for some reason?

Comment: If the page has any access restrictions in place (age, location, alcohol-related content), then you can not access any of its info using your app access token. It needs a user access token for a user that qualifies to see the page (or a page access token).

Comment: @CBroe Aha! That stuff is so poorly documented. Impossible to solve those issues. If you want, you can post it as an answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.
Also, people, if you downvote, leave a comment as to why. Is my question poorly formed? Stupid? Useless? Just let me know :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page has any access restrictions in place (age, location, alcohol-related content), then you can not access any of its info using your app access token.

It needs a user access token for a user that qualifies to see the page (or a page access token).